# ASP.NET Identity CreateAsync returning Error "Name cannot be null or empty."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I've tried every answer I could find on SO. I am trying to add Identity to my ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I am using Database first. There is already an existing database. I used the scripts from this GitHub to create the identity tables in my database.

https://gist.github.com/jeroenheijmans/8fa79427abc25a864cb055616644172f

Here is my Startup.cs file

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new AppDbContext());
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<RoleManager<AspNetRole>>((options, context) =>
          new RoleManager<AspNetRole>(
              new RoleStore<AspNetRole>(context.Get<AppDbContext>())));


        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")


        });

    }
```

Here is my ApplicationUserManager:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new AppDbContext());
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<RoleManager<AspNetRole>>((options, context) =>
          new RoleManager<AspNetRole>(
              new RoleStore<AspNetRole>(context.Get<AppDbContext>())));


        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")


        });

    }
```

Here is my register action:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register()
        {
            var model = (RegisterUserModel)Session["RegisterAccount"];
            var user = new AspNetUser()
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email
            };
            var userManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            IdentityResult addUserResult = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
}
```

My Role class

```
public partial class AspNetRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public AspNetRole(string name) { Name = name; }
    }
```

My User Class

```
 public partial class AspNetUser : IdentityUser
{

}
```

My DbContext

```
         public partial class AppDbContext: IdentityDbContext<AspNetUser>
{
        public AppDbContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `model.Email` value. It seems that it is null/empty. To make sure, put the `Register` method into a `try-catch` block and try to extract more details about the error/exception:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register()
{
  try
  {
    var model = (RegisterUserModel)Session["RegisterAccount"];
    var user = new AspNetUser()
    {
      UserName = model.Email,
      Email = model.Email
    };
    var userManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    IdentityResult addUserResult = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    if (!addUserResult.Succeeded)
    {
      //loop over addUserResult.Errors for more detail
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    //here, check the exception for more details
  }
}
```

Comment: The model.Email is populated as expected. The try catch block does not throw an exception. addUserResult.Succeeded is false with the Error: "Name cannot be null or empty."